# Idiomatic way in Laravel to manage permissions with field level specificity

Tags: laravel, permissions

I am new to Laravel and I want to make data in my database available via RESTFUL API.  I need to control permissions of data objects with field level specificity.  I was curious what is the idiomatic way to do this in Laravel?

For example, I will have a database table called `PrintMachine` that has the fields `Id,MachineName,ActivityStatus,ManufacturingYear`.  I want to assign the following permissions:

- Web Administrators get Read and Edit access to all records and all fields in `PrintMachine`
- Factory Managers get Read and Edit access to the `PrintMachine.MachineName and PrintMachine.ActivityStatus` fields for all records and get no access to any other fields in `PrintMachine`.
- Floor Operators get Read access to the `PrintMachine.MachineName` field for all records and get no access to any other fields in `PrintMachine`.

People told me to consider [Spatie Module](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) and also read [Gates and Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization), but it's not clear how either achieves field level permissions on their own.

The other option I was considering was to custom create my own solution by:

- for GET requests, create three ViewModels called `PrintMachineAdmin,PrintMachineManager,PrintMachineOperator`, each class with properties accessible to the corresponding roles.
- for POST/PUT requests, I'll have to write my own conditional statements to validate data based on the users roles

Is there a more idiomatic way to develop the a feature for field level permissions for restful apis?

Comment: you're question is too vague, too many possible solutions. The read part is seperate from thr write part. use midleware per access type and a group of controller per role. the reste is the same for all.

Answer (score 0):

So many options. An implementation of role and permission structure can achieve this and you can most certainly do this via the Spatie Module.

Eg adapted from spatie documentation:

```
$role = Role::create(['name' => 'Manager']); //db has roles table
//or if already created 
//$role = Role::where('name', 'Manager')->first();

$permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'edit PrintMachine.MachineName']); //db permissions table

$role->givePermissionTo($permission); //now manager role has been assigned permission to edit machine name.

//assigning role to user
$user = User::create(['name'=> 'Manager User']); //or get existing
$user->assigneRole($role); //now this user has edit access to machine name

//to see if user has access
if( $user->hasPermissionTo('edit PrintMachine.MachineName') )
  //do efit
//OR if you want to check using role
if( $user->hasRole('Manager')
  //do manager stuff

//and in view you can use @can blade directive
@can( 'edit PrintMachine.MachineName' )
  //authenticated user can edit machine name //show edit button/form
@endcan
//similarly @role directive will do the check using role
```

For super admins in `AuthServiceProvider`'s `boot` method.

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
 return $user->hasRole('Super Admin') ? true : null;
});
```

Gate's `before` method precedes all other gate operations so all other permissions can be overridden here.